# Having a difficult time creating a regex involving special characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to create a regex that matches on the following characters

`'<', '>', '(', ')', '[', ']', '\', '.', ',', ';', ':', '@', '"'`

I built the string

`String reg = "< | > | \\( | \\) | \\[ | \\] | \\\\ | \\. | , | ; | : | @ | \" | \\s"`

however it doesn't seem to be working when i do the following.

`String s = "h\"; //this is passed in via console input, read by Scanner()`
`if(s.matches(".*"+reg+".*")
   //do stuff`

it doesn't work. I'm not sure how to properly represent that string as a regex I guess and was hoping someone could point out what was off.

Comment: Oh and change matches for find, and remove the .* bits, or wrap the inner part in brackets, or change the inner part to use a [] group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for this, use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) instead.

```
[<>()\[\]\\,\.;:@\"]
```

A character class matches one of the characters that are inside the square brackets.

In Java:

```
String reg = "[<>()\\[\\]\\\\,\\.;:@\"\\s]"
```

Comment: why doesn't the '|' symbol work in this case, or does it not ever?

Comment: @Dave, sorry after automatic search/replace it looked like it would belong to the `.`. Added.

Comment: @sreya, the `|` is the alternation operator. it works, but in your case the spaces belongs also to the regex alternatives. The character class does not need the `|`. You can just list your characters (with proper escaping for character classes.)

Comment: Also worth noting that in the original, the .* being added to the start and end belong to the first and last option. To make the alternation work, they would also need to use brackets or change the matches for a find (without the .*) as I said in my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
String regex = "[<>\\(\\)\\[\\]\\\\,\\.;:@\"]";
```